# How can I prove that if $\ trace(C)=0 $ then $C=AB-BA$?

Tags: matrices

If $C = M_{n \times n}(F)$  and $\text{trace}(C)=0$  then $\exists{A,B}$ s.t $C=AB-BA$.

Comment: I think you might want $C \in M_{n \times n}(F)$ instead of  $C = M_{n \times n}(F)$.  Cheers!

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Please tell us what your thoughts are for this problem. Can you prove this in the $2 \times 2$ case? When $F$ is the field of real numbers? Does the reverse implication hold?

Comment: (Note that all of the discussion besides [the Albert-Muckenhoupt paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mmj/1028990168) seems to be beating around the bush.)